# Find a hex value in string form in a list of other string types in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a lists like the following:

```
['', '', '', 'VALUE', '0x01234', '__INT_S', '0', 'T_DURATION_10', '0', '120\n']
```

I need to look for the hex value 0x01234 in the above string to use it in further processing

I tried

```
try:
    val = [hex(val) for val in int_vals]
```

but it didnt work because all the strings lists are a mix of strings integers and hex values.

I guess I could loop through the list and see if the value is hex convertible, but there are a lot of lists and  I wanted a less time consuming approach if possible.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the re module to extract the hexadecimal values from the list.

```
import re

lst = ['', '', '', 'VALUE', '0x01234', '__INT_S', '0', 'T_DURATION_10', '0', '120\n']
hex_values = [x for x in lst if re.match(r'0x[0-9a-fA-F]+', x)]
```